# Few values in filter (template django)

Tags: python, django

The main idea in the following: I have a list and a value, which I get from template. So, I need to take a first element of that list -

```
list['value']
```

In template I have:

```
{% load get_number %}
{{  list, value |get_number }}
```

in get_number.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='get_number')
def get_number(arr, value):
    return arr[int(value)]
```

But it doesnt work. I search in Google, it said, that Django doesnt support a few elements in the filter (    {{  list, value |get_number }}). Its very strange to me, because in php I can do $list['value'] without any filtres, etc. How to fix that?

Comment: What's wrong with the `slice` filter?

Comment: Also the file name `get_number.py` and filter name should not be same. rename your file to `my_tags.py` or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do like this

```
{{  list|get_number:value }}
```

FYI: you can use a dot notation to index the list in template

```
{{list.0}} or {{list.1}}
```